# Which validation rule do I use to exclude numbers in a text field?

Tags: validation-rule

I have a field where i don't want any numbers in it.
How do i set up the validation rule?

I tried playing around with ISNUMBER.

NOT ISNUMBER(ShippingCity)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use below Validation Rule.

```
NOT(REGEX(ShippingCity, "[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Vinay!